# Writing to then Reading from a File Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am writing a Ruby CGI program that will append to a file (or create one if it doesn't exist, then write), and should then immediately read the file and return the output as a string. I have a method that works, however, I'm looking to optimizing it as the one that I'm using doesn't seem like the most efficient method. I'm relatively new to Ruby, so any suggestions would be great. I've looked over the documentation for File in Ruby, but I'm just a little uncertain about memory usage and optimization. Thank you very much.

```
def writeToFile(valuesToWrite)
   out_file = File.new("out.txt", "a+")
   out_file.puts(valuesToWrite)

   fhandle = File.new("out.txt","a+")
   lines = fhandle.readlines()

   return lines
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write as below :

```
def write_to_file(values_to_write)
   offset = File.size("out.txt")
   File.write("out.txt", values_to_write, offset)
   File.readlines("out.txt")
end
```

[`IO::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-write) doc is saying :-

> Opens the *file*, optionally *seeks* to the given *offset*, writes string, then returns the length written. **write ensures the file is closed before returning**. If *offset* is not given, the file is *truncated*. Otherwise, it is *not truncated*.

Read also [`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines).

The point here is, I don't need to think about file closing, it will be done by Ruby itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def writeToFile(values_to_write)
  out_file = File.new("out.txt", "a+")
  out_file.puts(values_to_write)
  out_file.rewind
  lines = out_file.readlines
  out_file.close
  lines
end
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit: The variable name has to stay the same as in the argument list.

Comment: That was my mistake.. change it as per the Ruby convention we follow. don't need to rollback it.. :)